# OwlCarousel 2 - reinit after page orientation change

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using OwlCarousel 2 beta for mobile version of my website. Quantity of showd images depends of screen width

```
var owl = $("#owl-demo");
  if (screen.availWidth < $(window).width()) {
    var sWidth = screen.availWidth / 300;
  } else {
    var sWidth = $(window).width() / 300;
  }
  var qua = Math.floor(sWidth);
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items : qua,
    autoWidth: false,
    autoHeight: false,
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<img src=\"/images/larrow.png\" width=\"24\">','<img src=\"/images/rarrow.png\" width=\"24\">'],
    pagination: false
  });
```

After page orientation change I want to reinit owlCarousel with new value of qua.

Tried

```
owl.trigger('destroy.owl');
```

and then

```
owl.owlCarousel({
      items : qua
...
})
```

After orientation change (or window width change) it breaks the page layout. Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wgj7y86y/1/

Any ideas, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OwlCarousel 2, but jQuery can do this using the .resize() method which is a shortcut to .on('resize', handler). It will listen for a change to the browser's size and then fire a function in response to that resize that can help you deal with any changes to the layout you experience.

[jQuery API resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: resize is working fine. Problem is with owl-carousel plugin reload

Comment: @George Apparently this is a known problem with owl-carousel. In another thread this was suggested as code for a work around. Since I don't use owl-carousel I would claim that it worked for me, but it might be worth a look.

Comment: @George You might also consider looking up the most recent version of owl-carousel and using that, it seems that this bug may have been fixed in later releases, but again just another troubleshooting approach.

Comment: Only solution - it's page reload:( Maybe in next releases this bug will be fixed...